# Limiting access of rdp to a certain IP only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

How can I enable just machines in one subnet (i.e. my home PC and the home network as a whole) to rdp to my servers and nothing else?

Answer (score 11):

In `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`, find the Remote Desktop (TCP-In) rule and open it. Navigate to the `Scope` tab and set the `Remote IP address` field to whatever you'd like it to be. Make sure you're applying it to the correct network profile as well (all, domain, private, or public).

[image]

Comment: @ChrisS It was the pen from the snipping tool! Though, I am also a pro at mspaint.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup an inbound rule within your windows firewall to only allow the ranges of your network to use RDP into your servers.